# Vaadin 14 - Grid Column Header Formatting

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I have some special characters in some of my column headers, such as "-" and "*". When these column names are rendered in the Grid, they include a space before and after the sequence.

In other words, if my original string was "CUR-A1" then it would be displayed as "CU R- A1" instead.

Is there any way to disable this kind of auto-formatting?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I added a Header with ABC-1-* and this stays as is. Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli found the error - turns out converting each header with camelCaseToHumanFriendly isn't a good idea, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a pretty simple fix - I was using SharedUtil.camelCaseToHumanFriendly(header) for each header, which introduced the strange formatting.